# When did Ford start putting the starter solenoid on the starter instead of on the fender?

Tags: ford, starter, solenoid

When did Ford start putting the starter solenoid on the starter instead of on the fender?

Last time I worked on one was 1973, and due to a hole in the fender, I showed the owner how I could start it without opening the hood.  But I have to crawl under (hard work at my age) for the E-450 I bought last month.

Comment: Well, on the F150, it looks like it went away around 2004-2005 timeframe ... but I don't know for sure about any of the other vehicles.

Comment: Woops, I was wrong ... looks like it was 1992 when they started putting the solenoid on the starter for the F150 ... again, I don't know anything beyond that, but I'd bet the rest of the models quit using it around that time as well.

Comment: Reasonable guess.  I was just curious—not like I have a choice.  :-)

Comment: About the time starters used the solenoid to move the pinion into engagement with the flywheel before full current was given to the motor part. And that was happening for many makes of car well prior to the ‘90s - Ford may not have been in the lead with using that technology.